# ESP-IDF: ESP32S3 DFU when USB CDC is active

Tags: esp-idf

I have some trouble to reflash the ESP32S3 after activating the USB-CDC (tinyUSB). So basically the only option at the moment is to press the button to go into the bootloader mode at startup to reflash the device.

Now assume I have the device connected to a SBC in the field and communication is only over USB-CDC, I cannot send someone to press the button for a DFU. One could do a custom bootloader to solve this problem, but i would like to use the standard idf tools provided and I think it should work.

For example for the Arduino IDE there this features seems to be available:

(https://espressif-docs.readthedocs-hosted.com/projects/arduino-esp32/en/latest/tutorials/cdc_dfu_flash.html)

I cannot find anything similar for the ESP-IDF, does anyone have a suggestion how this could be done?